# refreshControl extension does not show spinner after imagePicker

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, extension-methods, uirefreshcontrol

I wrote an extension that allows me to show a refreshControl on a regular tableView in a UIViewController. The code below works perfectly on the viewDidLoad() and when pull to refresh.

**Extension:**

```
extension UITableView
{
    func findRefreshControl () -> UIRefreshControl?
    {
        for view in subviews
        {
            if view is UIRefreshControl
            {
                print("The refresh control: \(view)")
                return view as? UIRefreshControl
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    func addRefreshControlWith(sender: UIViewController, action: Selector, view: UIView)
    {
        guard findRefreshControl() == nil else { return }

        let refreshControl = UIRefreshControl()
        refreshControl.addTarget(sender, action: action, for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)

        view.addSubview(refreshControl)
    }

    func showRefreshControlWith(attributedTitle: String? = nil)
    {
        findRefreshControl()?.attributedTitle = NSAttributedString(string: attributedTitle!)
        findRefreshControl()?.beginRefreshing()
    }

    func hideRefreshControl ()
    {
        findRefreshControl()?.endRefreshing()
    }
}
```

**Callees in ViewController: (Triggerend by observe events)**

```
private func showLoader()
    {
        tableView.showRefreshControlWith(attributedTitle: "Loading Profile".localized())
    }

    private func hideLoader()
    {
        tableView.hideRefreshControl()
    }
```

**Observers:**

```
_ = presenter.profilePictureUploadingPending.skip(first: 1).observeNext { _ in self.showLoader() }
_ = presenter.profilePictureUploaded.skip(first: 1).observeNext { _ in self.hideLoader() }
```

However, when I enter the UIImagePicker to upload a photo in my app and return back to the viewController it should trigger the the spinning process again until the photo is uploaded successfully.

I debugged my code and it is firing up the methods but the spinner disappeared from the view hierarchy subviews and is not showing up...

I am not sure how i can solve this issue but I really appreciate any help from you guys!

Thanks,
Kevin.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved with following solution:**

```
private func showLoader()
    {
        DispatchQueue.global(qos: .default).async {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.contentOffset.x = 1
                self.tableView.contentOffset.y = -81
                self.tableView.showRefreshControlWith(attributedTitle: "LOADING_PROFILE".localized())
            }
        }
    }
```